# Android Java: Receive Image over Socket

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, outputstream

i have a communication App over sockets.
The Client sends an Image to the server:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = MyClient.socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
            os.flush();
```

On the server side i want to receive the Image, but at the moments it just shows many different characters. If the Client just sends a text i receive it with:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String text = input.readLine();
```

But how can i "decode" the byte[] on the Server Side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogously to how you sent that image. Simply use an `InputStream` object like this:

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[MAX_SIZE];
int count = stream.read(data);
```

Both objects (sending and receiving) are compatible this way, you just have to know the `byte` array size, it has to be the same on both places.

Comment: Okay that sounds easier than i thought, but what do if have to do with that int count?

Comment: Nothing, actually. It just returns the number of bytes read, but you don't need it, calling that you'll store the array in your `data` object.

Comment: Ah okay and than i can get it to a Bitmap with the Bitmapfactory right?

Comment: Sure, once you get that `byte[]` you can set it to whatever you need, `BitmapFactory` works with them too.